# XML Parsing from Content response of Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to get XML result but not in a string as I do:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://#####">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns0:ResumeOrderResponse xmlns:ns0="http://####" xmlns:ns1="http://######" ns1:transactionID="*********-">
            <ns0:ResponseStatus ns1:code="1">
                <ns1:message>Order  not found</ns1:message>
            </ns0:ResponseStatus>
        </ns0:ResumeOrderResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is the way I am handling it:

```bsh
$header = @{"Authorization" = '********';"SOAPAction"='ResumeOrder'}
$post = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $header -Method Post -Body $xml -ContentType "application/soap+xml"
$bn = [xml]$post.Content

Write-Output $bn
```

I am trying to get just the line in the element "ns1:message", which is in this case "Order  not found".

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're facing. `$bn` should contain an XML object representing the XML data returned by the request. Is that not the case? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the "ns1: message" value like,

```
$bn.Envelope.Body.ResumeOrderResponse.ResponseStatus.message
```

Hope it helps!

Here is a sample which I tested locally,

```
$xmlString = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://#####">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns0:ResumeOrderResponse xmlns:ns0="http://####" xmlns:ns1="http://######" ns1:transactionID="*********-">
            <ns0:ResponseStatus ns1:code="1">
                <ns1:message>Order  not found</ns1:message>
            </ns0:ResponseStatus>
        </ns0:ResumeOrderResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
'@


$xmlString.Envelope.Body.ResumeOrderResponse.ResponseStatus.message
```

Comment: wow, how easy that actually was... works like a charm! thaks friend! :)